# JavaScript thumbnail swiper / slider doesn't work properly

Tags: slider, swiper.js

I'm trying to make a simple swiper / slider with thumbnails. It works fine, the only problem is, that slides on the right, which do not have to be shown yet, are present on the screen, which makes the swiper wider than the webpage...

[Here ist the picture, how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdudZ.jpg)

Does anyone know, how to fix it? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for you help.

```js
var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
      spaceBetween: 10,
      slidesPerView: 'auto',
      freeMode: true,
      watchSlidesVisibility: true,
      watchSlidesProgress: true,
    });
    var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
      spaceBetween: 10,
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
      grabCursor: true,
      thumbs: {
        swiper: galleryThumbs
      }
    });
```

```css
html,
    body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

.swiper-slide{
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
}
    .gallery-top {
      height: 60%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .gallery-thumbs {
      height: 20%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 10px 0;
    }

    .gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide {
      width: 25%;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 0.4;
    }
    .gallery-thumbs  img{
        width:40%
    }

    .gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide-thumb-active {
      opacity: 1;
    }

.gallery-top img{
  width: 400px;
  height:400px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:100px) and (max-width:500px){
  .gallery-top img{
  width: 300px;
  height:300px;
    }
  .gallery-thumbs  img{
        width:100%
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper-container gallery-top">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
       <div class="swiper-slide slide-top">
         <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/22/200/300'
         alt='slide 1' />
       </div>
       <div class="swiper-slide slide-top">
        <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300'
        alt='slide 2' />
       </div>
       <div class="swiper-slide slide-top">
        <img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300'
        alt='slide 3' />
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Arrows -->
<div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-black"></div>
<div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-black"></div>

<div class="swiper-container gallery-thumbs">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300'
            alt='slide 1' />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300'
            alt='slide 2' />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300'
            alt='slide 3' />
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake.

The `CDN` is for **swiper 8**

https://unpkg.com/swiper@8.4.4/swiper-bundle.min.css

But your markup is of the old versions of swiper.

https://swiperjs.com/migration-guide

Change `swiper-container` to `swiper`

```css
 html,
  body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .swiper-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .swiper-slide{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .gallery-top {
    height: 60%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .gallery-thumbs {
    height: 20%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px 0;
  }

  .gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  .gallery-thumbs img{
    width:40%
  }

  .gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide-thumb-active {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .gallery-top img{
    width: 400px;
    height:400px;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css">

<div class="swiper gallery-top">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide slide-top">
      <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/22/200/300'
           alt='slide 1' />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide slide-top">
      <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300'
           alt='slide 2' />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide slide-top">
      <img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300'
           alt='slide 3' />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Arrows -->
<div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-black"></div>
<div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-black"></div>

<div class="swiper gallery-thumbs">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300'
           alt='slide 1' />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300'
           alt='slide 2' />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300'
           alt='slide 3' />
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<script>   
  var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
    spaceBetween: 10,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    freeMode: true,
    watchSlidesVisibility: true,
    watchSlidesProgress: true,
  });
  var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
    spaceBetween: 10,
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    grabCursor: true,
    thumbs: {
      swiper: galleryThumbs
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: That worked, thank you very much! But if I put css and js scripts outside of the page file and link them from external files it doesn't work... Do you know why it can happen? The paths are correct.

Comment: Check the CSS order. You should load the custom css after swiper css. Also inspect your code. Check for console errors.